# Sorl-thumbnail generates black lines and undesired crops

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

I'm using Sorl Thumbnail 12.4a1, Pillow 4.0.0 in a django project

It works fine for most images but for some of them I run into unexpected behaviour.

The original image is portrait jpg 765x1110

After running this code: get_thumbnail('/media/ryzsUIKZVUc.jpg', '464', upscale=False)

I receive a 464x320 image with black background on it's left and right and cropped on top and bottom

this is the original:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ia7906ec19xjhro/ryzsUIKZVUc.jpg?dl=0

and this is the result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/adgut5zkw4xln6e/62b2439654a00312defafddb862eda9b.jpg?dl=0

p.s.
tried to upload the original here as an image but it was automatically converted to portrait.. could it mean something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frame appears because of the exif tag. The size of the image is not correctly determined.

You can see this using `exiftool`:

```
$ exiftool ryzsUIKZVUc.jpg 
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.10
File Name                       : ryzsUIKZVUc.jpg
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 210 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2017:03:30 12:33:51+03:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2017:03:30 12:33:55+03:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2017:03:30 12:33:51+03:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-r--
File Type                       : JPEG
File Type Extension             : jpg
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
JFIF Version                    : 1.01
Comment                         : CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 99.
Exif Byte Order                 : Big-endian (Motorola, MM)
Processing Software             : Windows Photo Editor 10.0.10011.16384
Orientation                     : Rotate 270 CW
Software                        : Windows Photo Editor 10.0.10011.16384
Modify Date                     : 2017:03:07 09:28:15
Date/Time Original              : 2017:03:07 09:27:46
Create Date                     : 2017:03:07 09:27:46
Sub Sec Time Original           : 00
Sub Sec Time Digitized          : 00
Color Space                     : sRGB
Padding                         : (Binary data 2060 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Compression                     : JPEG (old-style)
X Resolution                    : 96
Y Resolution                    : 96
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Thumbnail Offset                : 4608
Thumbnail Length                : 8169
About                           : uuid:faf5bdd5-ba3d-11da-ad31-d33d75182f1b
Creator Tool                    : Windows Photo Editor 10.0.10011.16384
Image Width                     : 1110
Image Height                    : 765
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
Image Size                      : 1110x765
Megapixels                      : 0.849
Create Date                     : 2017:03:07 09:27:46.00
Date/Time Original              : 2017:03:07 09:27:46.00
Thumbnail Image                 : (Binary data 8169 bytes, use -b option to extract)
```

Or use `PIL`

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS
>>> 
>>> im = Image.open('ryzsUIKZVUc.jpg')
>>> exif = im._getexif()
>>> data = {}
>>> 
>>> for tag, value in exif.items():
...     decoded = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
...     data[decoded] = value
... 
>>> 
>>> data['Orientation']
8
```

To fix this, you can before generating a preview, (rotate image) save the picture without this tag.

For example,

```
def orient(image_path):
    """ Check are this img oriented """
    img = Image.open(image_path)
    # check is has exif data
    if not hasattr(img, '_getexif') or img._getexif() is None:
        return
    # if has information - try rotate img
    orientation = img._getexif().get(0x112)
    rotate_values = {3: 180, 6: 270, 8: 90}
    if orientation in rotate_values:
        img = img.rotate(rotate_values[orientation], expand=True)
    img.save(image_path, quality=100)
```

Or easier, change the settings `THUMBNAIL_ORIENTATION = False`. In this case, the image simply stops rotating. And no more black lines are created.

Answer (score 0):

This bug has already been fixed in the repository on the github.
This PR https://github.com/mariocesar/sorl-thumbnail/pull/233

But in pypi is still an old package. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sorl-thumbnail/12.4a1 updated at 2015-11-17

To use the new version, install the package directly from the github.

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/mariocesar/sorl-thumbnail.git#egg=sorl-thumbnail
```

After installation, you will need to clear the image cache

```
$ rm -rf path/to/media/cache/
$ python manage.py thumbnail clear
$ python manage.py thumbnail cleanup
```

Comment: Tried this version but received same result with it :(